# How to switch from inner frame to default page in selenium using core Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to switch from inner frame to default page in selenium using core Java?
Do I need to use `driver.switchto.defaultcontent()` twice? But it so what should I pass in this `defaultcontent()` bracket?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to pass anything if you want to use defaultcontent()
just write :

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

if you want to switch to another frame using index of the frame then try this method , and pass the frame value to the parameter

```
    public static void switchToFrameByIndex(int frameValue) {
    driver.switchTo().frame(frameValue);
}
```